# Connecting to local_stack kinesis using FlinkKinesis Producer fails

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, localstack

I have https://github.com/localstack/localstack running on my local to do some development with kinesis. The service is exposed through `localhost:4568` and I am able to interact with it using the aws cli.

For instance when I run this

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url http://localhost:4568/ kinesis create-stream --stream-name myStreamName --shard-count 1 --no-verify-ssl
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url http://localhost:4568/ kinesis list-streams
```

I get

```
{
    "StreamNames": [
        "myStreamName"
    ]
}
```

When I configure the `FlinkKinesisProducer` like this however

```
Properties kinesisConfig = new Properties();
        // Required configs
        kinesisConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1");
        kinesisConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, "x");
        kinesisConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "x");
        kinesisConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ENDPOINT, "http://localhost:4568");
        kinesisConfig.put("VerifyCertificate", "false");

        FlinkKinesisProducer<GenericRecord> kinesis = new FlinkKinesisProducer<GenericRecord>(new KinesisSerializationSchema<GenericRecord>() {
            @Override
            public ByteBuffer serialize(GenericRecord genericRecord) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getTargetStream(GenericRecord genericRecord) {
                return null;
            }
        }, kinesisConfig);
        kinesis.setFailOnError(true);
        kinesis.setDefaultStream("myStreamName");
        kinesis.setDefaultPartition("0");
```

and try to produce to the local kinesis sream, I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1640)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1620)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1602)
    at ApacheFlinkPoc.main(ApacheFlinkPoc.java:80)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PerJobMiniClusterFactory$PerJobMiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(PerJobMiniClusterFactory.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:874)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:74)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:573)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception was thrown while processing a record: Unable to connect to endpoint
Unable to connect to endpoint
Unable to connect to endpoint
Unable to connect to endpoint

Record has reached expiration

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisProducer.checkAndPropagateAsyncError(FlinkKinesisProducer.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisProducer.invoke(FlinkKinesisProducer.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:616)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:596)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:730)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.emitRecord(KafkaFetcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:150)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:200)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.onPutRecordResult(KinesisProducer.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.access$000(KinesisProducer.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler$1.run(KinesisProducer.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

For some reason `flink-kinesis` connector fails to connect to the `localhost:4568`
Please can someone advise on this?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: did you get any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

rather than passing the -

```
kinesisConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ENDPOINT, "http://localhost:4568");
```

pass like this -

```
kinesisConfig.put("KinesisEndpoint", "localhost")
kinesisConfig.put("KinesisPort", "4567")
kinesisConfig.put("VerifyCertificate","true")
```